# Cinnamon desktop not working properly

Tags: cinnamon

I have installed cinnamon-desktop along with gnome-shell.I logged in once using cinnamon(software rendering) and after that when I login using cinnamon the panel is not shown until I open any application using run command.Also the panel settings won't open
[image].[image]

What should I do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to just use Linux Mint.  It comes preinstalled with cinnamon so you don't have to go through the trouble of installing it.  If you need any apps that come preinstalled with Ubuntu, just install them from the repositories or through Mint's app store.